# Why Bootstrap 5 navbar does not collapsing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I try to compile Bootstrap 5 with sass but I think I miss importing some scss files. If I added `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">` navbar collapsing fine, but when I added my compailed css file navbar not collapsing.

Here is my navbar codes

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{site.baseurl}}">
      Workshop
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <!-- navlinks -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my main.scss codes

```css
// PATHS ARE TRUE
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";

// 4. Include any optional Bootstrap CSS as needed
// I GUEST MISSING IN HERE
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/card";

// 5. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 6. Add additional custom code here
```

And here is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/css/main.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <title>{{site.title}}</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/images/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  {{content}}

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why my navbar does not collapsing? Which scss files i have to import? I have read the documents but I missing something. Could not fix. Please help.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: How it is displaying now? share screenshot

Comment: @zainhassan I added screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this file too

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/transitions";
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a id for the navbar and change a style by giving it manually, it worked for me

Comment: how? can you share some codes?